# get current top left bottom and right position of a screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get the current left, top, bottom and right position of a screen, so i can animate my object perfectly. Is there anything to get current location? Any help would be nice.

**object position set:**

```
 $(this).animate
 ({
     left: $(window).scrollLeft(),
     top: $(window).scrollTop(),
     width: $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width(),
     height:  $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
 }, 500,
```

this issue now remain the bottom part after changing my code to @chad.

[image: <code>sample</code>]

Comment: i dont' think there is an api for that.

Comment: that means bad luck for me.

Comment: you could require the full screen api

Comment: full screen api. i would into that. i thought there would be a jquery or something like that. anyways thanku :)

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop(), $(window).scrollLeft(), $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(), $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width()`

Comment: @Chad: bottom problem now remaining just.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8DrQh/

Comment: for height this should make sense `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()` but i don't know why its not animating from the current top posotion

Comment: It looks like you might be scrolled down partway on the page.

Comment: yes i am scrolling down. without scrolling down this is fitting perfectly. is there a way i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

there is something in jQuery

The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document. When positioning a new element near another one and within the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful.

Returns an object containing the properties top and left.

https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: i will try and will give my response.

Answer (score 0):

API? Whats this got to do with an API?

check out http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-position-function/ - this may be of some help!